# Encrypting PII data with our own keys

Tags: encryption, shield-encryption, data-protection-and-privacy

I'm new to Salesforce and working on a problem being raised by my team. They have a requirement to encrypt all PII passing between our systems and Salesforce . Our company only allows for this data to be encrypted using RSA asymmetric key encryption. I am being told that this is not supported by Salesforce. Is this the case?

Comment: RSA / Asymmetric encryption is not typically used for encryption of field level data at rest.  I'd be curious to understand what the driver is for wanting to use that instead of symmetric key encryption like AES-256.

Comment: It's honestly a company standard that I have I inherited. The theory is that the data security team does not feel that passing private keys to public cloud providers is secure enough. 

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing encryption with signing?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need to manually encrypt anything to transfer it securely, you should be using proper https to communicate between your system and Salesforce.

Comment: If the "public" key they pass to Salesforce is used to decrypt data they don't want decrypted by any other system, it's not a public key, you just have a system with two co-equal private keys.

Comment: I think this requirement is confused or has been communicated to you poorly. I would encourage you to go back to the security team to get clarity on what is exactly required. Transmission security (via HTTPS, typically) is very different from at-rest security (Salesforce Platform Encryption).

Comment: I agree with the others here - this seems like a miscommunication or confusion around requirements.  Our Shield Platform Encryption doesn't require passing any key material to Salesforce, by default we'll generate key material utilizing HSMs and key lifecycle is entirely in your (customer) hands.  That said - customers who have a requirement for it can do bring your own keys.

Comment: That is actually not the case. Security has been quite clear and even spoke to salesforce about it being a limiting factor to our adoption over a year ago. It is required that we generate our own keys using our HSM's. It sounds like it is indeed not possible based on these responses. @JohnWhelan Will BYOK work with a public key?

Comment: You can generate your own keys with your HSM, but RSA/asymmetric encryption is not the technology we use to do encryption of data at rest.  Since the encrypt/decrypt operations happen solely on the Salesforce platform it doesn't make sense to use asymmetric encryption - symmetric encryption (AES in this case) is more appropriate.

Comment: Understood. And I agree. Just need to make a strong case to security for the exception. Thank you! Oh, and feel free to make that the answer and I can mark it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce doesn't support asymmetric data encryption at the user level, you can look at the [Crypto class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) to see what is supported in Apex.  It isn't supported because there isn't really a use case for it (it does support asymmetric encryption algorithms for signing data, since that is an appropriate use case for asymmetric encryption and not symmetric).  Once you've given someone the public key for the data you encrypted, it's effectively irrelevant whether or not you used asymmetric or symmetric encryption for the purpose of keeping the data secret, and symmetric encryption is both secure at smaller key sizes and faster overall due to the smaller size.

Candidly, if your security team doesn't understand the use cases of asymmetric vs symmetric encryption, I'd be very concerned that they are being trusted to secure PII.  Your company may want to consider hiring an outside firm to help educate your security team and test your existing implementations.

Comment: Thank you for the great link! Honestly, if you knew who I worked for you may re-consider your confidence. We hold many patents in this area that I guarantee you leverage regularly. :)

Comment: `Once you've given someone the public key for the data you encrypted, it's effectively irrelevant whether or not you used asymmetric or symmetric encryption` this is completely wrong and misleading. If you encrypt with RSA only the holder of private key can decrypt the data; symmetric algorithm means whoever holds the key used to encrypt can also decrypt.

Comment: @zaitsman I think you're getting hung up on public v private key, I probably should have just used the words encryption and decryption key.  My point is that both types of encryption have at least one key for encryption and at least one for decryption, if you encrypt with one key and give someone else the decryption key they can decrypt it whether or not that's a symmetric or asymmetric key.  As an aside, for RSA in particular the private key and public key can both decrypt each other's encrypted data, this is not a requirement for asymmetric systems though.

Comment: Which is why the security of SF is lax, as i do not want SF to be able to decrypt the message intended for my remote service when i did not share private keys with SF.

Comment: @zaitsman If you have a specific scenario that you're trying to figure out a solution for you can make another question.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian While you are correct in so much that Salesforce does not support asymmetric encryption, you're completely misleading saying there are no use cases for it. There is a huge need for Asymmetric encryption in Salesforce. Storing public keys securely(if even needed) is way more trivial than storing and transporting an AES key. Application Level Encryption (over and on top of TLS) is a fairly reasonable requirement that many Financial institutions now require. On top of that, some services require that JWT tokens encrypt their payload (not just sign). In fact its part of RFC7523.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian "Candidly, if your security team doesn't understand the use cases of asymmetric vs symmetric encryption, I'd be very concerned that they are being trusted to secure PII." Wow...just wow.

Answer (score 2):

With Salesforce Shield Platform Encryption you can generate your own keys with your HSM and use Bring Your Own Keys (BYOK), but RSA/asymmetric encryption is not the technology we use to do encryption of data at rest. Since the encrypt/decrypt operations happen solely on the Salesforce platform it doesn't make sense to use asymmetric encryption - symmetric encryption (AES in this case) is more appropriate, and is what we use (AES-256).